# How to page except master page block

Tags: 2010, custom-masterpage, dropdown

I have a dropdown in master page. Since I need that in all pages throughout site.

I have list OOTB view webparts and custom webparts on various pages.

When user changes value from dropdown, I need to refresh webparts but not master page block. Since the dropdown value will be used as a filter parameter in all webparts.

I am storing dropdown changed value in Cookies since that event is bind through jquery.

If not possible, then entire page refresh would also do, but as last option.

Any pointers how can I achieve?

PS: Not looking for query string option.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that if you are using filters against OOTB list view web parts in SP2010 then you have no choice but to use the query string and a page refresh. There may be a way to achieve this with some development effort and an ASP.Net UpdatePanel in a custom page layout.  If you filter a standard list using a standard UI approach (using the column headers) you should see the page refresh as SP puts filter parameters into the URL - this is effectively what you are looking to achieve through the use of a custom dropdown.

Comment: For OOTB webparts, I am doing some customization, and generating custom Query and using it to filter LVWP